# Apache status is 200 but the content length is zero

Tags: apache

In Apache (version is 2.2.15) when I send a request, sometimes the response status is 200, but content is empty.

Not all response is empty, just sometimes.

Any suggestions or somebody know the reason or give me some suggestion?

Comment: What contents are failing to be returned? Is it PHP or static contents as well?

Comment: Strangely enough I happen to have the same problem with Apache 2.4.7 after upgrading to current Ubuntu four days ago.

Comment: returnen no contents;after testing,the apache has got the request,but it did not send to resin.  sometimes happen,why?  the apache versin  did not meet the resin version ? the apache version is  2.2.15,the resin version is 3.1.6

Comment: Also seems to happen here once in a while. Already checked all my code, there's no clue why it should be happening.